# jsTree check charasters editing text of node and limit the lenght text node then edit

Tags: jstree

Tell me whether it is possible to limit the length of the text and typed characters when editing node?

```
 var items = {
                rename : {
                    label: "Rename",
                    action: function(obj) {
                        $("#tree").jstree(true).edit(node)


                    }
                },
```

Comment: I need to control which characters entered by the user and set the maximum number of characters in a name when he changes the name of the node. is it possible to do this by means of jstree? or whether you can get the text when the user enters it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud attach whatever handlers and attributes you need on the input box after calling `edit`:

```
$('#jstree').jstree(true).edit(1);
$('.jstree-rename-input').attr('maxLength', 6);
```

Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/497/